# Comparing properties on a list of objects to a string list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a list of objects that look vaguely like the following pseudocode:

```
class myObj:
    self.init(i, s):
        myInt = i
        myString = j
```

And we pseudocode lists, one of them with the important properties like this:

```
Mario = [MyObj(0, 'foo1'), MyObj(0, 'foo2'), MyObj(0, 'foo3')]
Luigi = ['bar1', bar2']
```

Then we try to remove any of `MyObj` from `Mario` that does not match a string in `Luigi`:

```
for coin in Mario:
    if coin.myString not in Luigi:
        Mario.remove(coin)
```

Problem is, this only loops twice, then exits, with `len(Mario) == 1`, instead of zero.

using

```
Peach = [(myObj)x for x.myString in Mario if x not in Luigi]
```

errors with:  `"[" was not closed`

How can I compare the strings in Luigi to all of Mario's myStrings, and discard the objects that do not fit?

I checked the following SO questions, and none helped:
[Remove all values within one list from another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514961/remove-all-values-within-one-list-from-another-list/30353802)

[Comparing list of objects to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63545628/comparing-list-of-objects-to-a-string)

[Remove all the elements that occur in one list from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211209/remove-all-the-elements-that-occur-in-one-list-from-another)

Comment: What do you expect `(myObj)x` and `for x.myString in ...` to do? This is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I had been struggling with this for like 2 days, and as I was typing it out, a solution came to me.

If I use `List Comprehension`, I can do the following:

```
    Peach = [coin for coin in Mario if coin.myString in Luigi]
```

This returns the correct objects, and it looks like it preserves ordering, too.